# query mongodb and generics

Tags: java, mongodb, generics

I am using spring mongoDB and I would like to write a query using generics, such as

```
@Override
public  <T extends Common> T find(T t)
{
    return mongoTemplate.findById(t.getId(), Common.class);
}
```

However, this gives me an error, and I can't use

```
@Override
public  <T extends Common> T find(T t)
{
    return mongoTemplate.findById(t.getId(), T.class);
}
```

So I am stuck.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass a `Class<T>` instance to the method:

```
@Override
public  <T extends Common> T find(T t, Class<T> clazz) {
    return mongoTemplate.findById(t.getId(), clazz);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works with the first option find(T t, Class<T> clazz)